# i can't see files in git repository

Tags: git, ssh

I created a git repository via ssh. It works but i can't see files in directory.

remote(ssh):

```
mkdir test.com
cd test.com
git init

client(git bash)
cd /apache/htdocs
git clone git://myserverip/test.com
cd test.com
git add --all .
git commit -a -m "first"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
mkdir test.com
cd test.com
git init
cd .git
cd hooks
vi post-receive
chmod +x post-receive
```

post-receive

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ..
env -i git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 2):

i think, you must be add file and commit in repository on the server. why you dont try bare repository?

if you need to push commits by remote try this commands:

on the server create repository:

```
cd /usr/local/git/    ## or your own repo destination
mkdir repo.git
cd repo.git
git init
touch README
git add .
git commit -a -m "start my repository"
```

on the client such as ubuntu:

```
git clone ssh://User@serverip:sshport/usr/local/git/repo.git myrepo
cd myrepo
git branch someUser   # create new branch
vim README   ## some change on the file
git add README
git commit -a -m "some change by someUser"    ## user commit changes
git push origin someUser   ## push commit to server
```

after user push change's system admin must be merge commits, simple way is:

```
cd /usr/local/git/repo.git
git merge someUser   ##  merge repo by user commit
```

Answer (score 1):

Pushing files into a remote repository does not update the file tree (the "index"). It updates the store of objects.

To update the tree to reflect the stored object, you would have to do a `git reset --hard` in that remote repository to update it to the new `HEAD`.

This is a bad thing, and so remote repositories are usually set up as "bare": a special repository format for git hosting which doesn't have a working tree (and other differences: such as no `.git` directory: the config files are more conveniently stored in its root directory).

Use a bare repository for your upstream: `git init --bare`.

Comment: Also...he appears to be cloning an empty repository, adding nothing to it, and pushing it.

Comment: i will try it but i think, it is possible without --bare. because i have 3 repository and it works also it created by git init (without --bare) command. thanks for reply

Comment: It is possible without `--bare`, yes, but there are some inconveniences.